# C - Send one byte

Tags: c, arrays, ip, byte

Question is simple: how to send exactly one byte to some server.

I am trying to create a program for Windows in C which should be able to send exactly one byte to a given IP address. So, I simply need a function like this:

```
void sendByte(unsigned int ip, unsigned char byte){/**/}
```

I searched on MSDN and I found some functions which provide such a service (of course, program should be enabled in firewall etc.., I did that already), but these functions also write a header. For example, when I try to send one byte, it sends actually `1025` bytes. The first `1024` bytes are some junk data I don't want to be sent (like headers `Content-Length:...` etc). Is there a way to send exactly one byte?

What I have also found is some libraries and stand-alone executable files which provide something like that. But, I don't want to include anything except standard C libraries and also `<windows.h>`, and I don't want to use 3rd stand-alone executables.

I have searched on StackOverflow and MSDN, but I found nothing helpful. Is there an easy way to do it using only standard libraries and windows.h only? Not other libraries and plugins and programs please.

Comment: When you send an IP packet it is never just one byte. Perhaps reading this will help you understand better what exactly happens under the hood: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model (BTW, IP is a part of Layer 4: Transport Layer)

Comment: I wouldn't have downvoted it. Usually, good questions contain a piece of code that shows what you've tried and what is the problem you are facing. To be honest, I think you can't achieve what you ask for. The reason is that although you don't need the extra "first 1024 bytes", the network protocols that pass the data around might not work without it (perhaps you can reduce the overhead, but getting it to 1 byte seems impossible over IP).

Comment: @DoronYakovlev-Golani. I just read the whole article you posted. If I understood correctly, OSI model is implementation-dependant. Does it mean that, theoretically, I can create my own OS and my own internet driver so that I will be able to send exactly 1 byte (or maybe even exactly 1 bit)?

Comment: Unfortunately, the `standard c libraries` have no concept of network communications. That ability is added by non-standard libraries.  So, in answer to your question, given your restrictions, the answer is `no`

Comment: One byte would not even cover the destination address ;(